# Prove that if $p$ is a prime and $k$ is an integer, there are two integers $x$ and $y$ that satisfy $x^{2} + y^{2} + k \equiv p$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory

Prove that if $p$ is a prime and $k$ is an integer, there are two integers $x$ and $y$ that satisfy 
$$ x^2 + y^2 + k \equiv 0 \pmod p. $$

Comment: what do you mean by the symbol with three dots in a vertical line?

Comment: It means "can be without residue divided by"

Comment: @EdwardJiang $k$ isn't chosen freely, it is given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hereafter we assume that $p$ is odd, $p=2$ case is trivial.

We can reformulate your problem: show that $\forall$ prime $p$, sum of squares of $2$ integers can take any residual when divided by $p$. We will use the notation $p=2q-1$

To prove it, let us start with studying how many different residuals (when divided by $p$) can a square of an integer number have. Obviously, it is enough to study the residuals of $k \in \{0, 1, 2, \dots, p-1\}$, because they are cyclical.

The difference between $k_1^2$ and $k^2_2$, where $k_1, k_2 \in \{0, 1, 2, \dots, p-1\}$, is

$$(k_2-k_1)(k_2+k_1)$$

Note that this expression has $0$ residual $\mod p$ if and only if $k_2+k_1=p$.

Thus, the residuals of squares of $\{0, 1, 2, \dots, q\}$ (as above,  $p=2q-1$) are all different.

So what remains to prove is that: if you have $0$ and $q$ different numbers $\in \{1, 2, \dots, 2q\}$, then the sum of 2 of these numbers (a number can be used twice) can take any values between $0$ and $2q$. To prove this, we do not need to use the fact that $2q+1$ is prime. This can be proved by induction. Base, $p=3, \ q=1$, is trivial. Transition reduces to proving that, among 0 and $q$ pairwise different numbers $\in \{1,2,\dots,2q\}$, we can select $2$ which sum is $2q$ and $2$ which sum is $2q+1$. This can be proved by absurd.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be the set of of squares in $\mathbf{Z}/p\mathbf{Z}$ and let $Y$ be set of numbers of the form $-k - y^2$ in $\mathbf{Z}/p\mathbf{Z}$. There are $(p + 1)/2$ quadratic residues in $\mathbf{Z}/p\mathbf{Z}$, so these two sets are each of cardinality $(p + 1)/2$. Since $\mathbf{Z}/p\mathbf{Z}$ only has $p$ elements, though, this means they must have some element in common, i.e. there exists $x^2 \in A$ and $-k - y^2 \in B$ such that $$x^2 \equiv -k - y^2 \pmod p,$$ $$x^2 + y^2 + k \equiv 0 \pmod p.$$